# Where do I place a font, or other resources, which my program uses?

Tags: c++, linux, resources, assets, directory-structure

I am writing a graphical application for linux, which requires a particular font. Currently, I have the following setup:

```
root-dir/
  include/
    foo.h
  src/
    foo.cpp
  fontname/
    fontlicense.txt
    font-regular.ttf
  main.cpp
  Makefile
```

The problem here is, although the program runs when I am currently in my development directory, it will not function if I install it to `/usr/local/bin` and try to run it anywhere else on the system.

In other words, how do I put `fontlicense.txt` and `fontregular.ttf` in a particular location, and expect it to be able to find it anywhere on the system?

And how would I make it override these resources with the ones in the current working directory, as well, so that I can test it in development with different resources?

(The same goes for other resources, such as graphics for the program.)

Comment: just google "Install fonts on Ubuntu <replace with your distro>"

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk I'd like my solution to work on anybody's system, not just on my own. (A `make install` would put the font in the proper location.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux apps should use fontconfig to locate fonts and install font files in the fontconfig default location (typically subdirectories of /usr/share/fonts)